# Manipulate to choose a variable in a list

Tags: manipulate

I have a simple question.

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
data2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

Manipulate[ListPlot[chooseData],
 {chooseData, {{data1, data2}}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}
 ]
```

How to perform this task? Choose to plot `data1`, or `data2` in the `Manipulate`.

Comment: You have one level of braces too many in the selection list. I addition to that, I'd suggest providing text labels with the names of the data sets for convenience, and pre-selecting an initial value for `chooseData`. For instance: `Manipulate[ListPlot[chooseData], {{chooseData, data1}, {data1 -> "data1", data2 -> "data2"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu} ]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove one level of braces:

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
data2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

Manipulate[
  ListPlot[chooseData], 
  {chooseData, {data1, data2}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}
]
```

Or a bit more sophisticated:

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
data2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
names = {"data1", "data2"};
ass = Association[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{names, {data1, data2}}]]

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[ass[chooseData]], {chooseData, names, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

or also:

```
data1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
data2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[ReleaseHold@chooseData], {chooseData, {HoldForm@data1, 
   HoldForm@data2}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to use HoldFirst, or something like that. Because in the list, I want to show the name of the variable, like data1, or data2. Your approach works, but in the PopupMenu, it shows the value of "data1" and "data2"

Comment: see the second example (and the third one) :)

Comment: wonderful! ReleaseHold! and Association!